# truncation hides radiobutton

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to truncate the label that displays the text of the radio button but when I succeeded the radiobutton dissapeared with the rest of the hidden text.
As shown here: [JSFiddle1](https://jsfiddle.net/tribeldragon/7L5yfa5o/1/)

The truncation doesn't work in fiddle for me but it works in my code. I just want the radiobutton to still be shown as here: [JSFiddle2](https://jsfiddle.net/tribeldragon/7L5yfa5o/2/) `overflow: hidden;`

Comment: you have the code, whats the problem ?

Comment: @mrid the problem is that with JSFiddle1 in my code on my pc it truncates the text like I want, but it hides the radiobutton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have minus margin on your label which hides the checkbox. Remove the minus margin and apply more padding to the label.